# When comparing a product to a patent's claim what visual aide is used?

Tags: infringement, claim-chart

What format is used in laying out a patent's claim against a product's features to do a good side-by-side comparison?

Answer (score 1):

Usually a table called a "claim chart" is created. It is literally side-by-side, element-by-element. I am including an example:
[image]

[a link to the spreadsheet.](http://ebookbrowsee.net/apple-7-479-949-palm-pre-infringement-claim-chart-xlsx-d488599852)